# Get text between <span> tag that is inside another <span> tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

My current code to get the content I need looks like this:

```
#BeautifulSoup
textContent = []
headline = soup.find('a', attrs={"class":"title"}).text
review = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"text show-more__control"}).text
rating = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"rating-other-user-rating"})

textContent.append(headline)
print(headline)
textContent.append(review)
print(review)
textContent.append(rating)
print(rating)
```

I get the title and the text of the review but not the rating because this information is in a different "tag-system" than the other info. On the html code it looks like this:

```
<span class="rating-other-user-rating">
        <svg class="ipl-icon ipl-star-icon  " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
            <path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"></path>
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
        </svg>
            <span>6</span><span class="point-scale">/10</span>
        </span>
```

The information I want to get is the "6". Obviously, I can't just go by "soup.find.---.text() because it's a None-Object.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it's returning none because you have it looking for `<div>`, not span

Comment: Start by looking for a `span` element instead of a `div`. If you are using BeautifulSoup 4.7 or newer, use a CSS selector: `.select_one('span.rating-other-user-rating span')`

Comment: @MartijnPieters that'll work fine in earlier versions of BS4 as well - although that soupsieve looks amazing - thanks for tweeting about that - that's gone on my "things to play with when I get a minute" :)

Comment: @JonClements: probably, but I just can't be bothered right now to find out again what exactly the old selector engine supported. It was broken and limited in weird ways, and with soupsieve here we can just move on and use a decent engine instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `soup.select_one('span.rating-other-user-rating > span').text` works fine here... I might have to check out the soupsieve project properly at some point as it'd be nice if it also did a few things that scrapy's done to extend cssselectors using lxml... being able to do something like: `soup.select('span.rating-other-user-rating > span::attr(text)')` would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Change the `'div`' to `'span'`

2)

- a) then you can get the text
- b) strip away the whitespace, to get    `6/10`
- c) Split at the `'/'`
- d) take element in that list at    index `[0]`

**Replace:**

```
rating = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"rating-other-user-rating"})
```

**With:**

```
rating = soup.find('span', attrs={"class":"rating-other-user-rating"}).text.strip().split('/')[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (rating)
6
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just copied the wrong code. I had 'span' in my code but still didn't have a clue how to continue and get this output

Comment: @Narallio note that you can just use `soup.select_one('span.rating-other-user-rating > span').text` as well on your HTML snippet you showed...

Comment: Thanks! That solution actually seems easier and better to remember for later. Just haven't used "select_one" before since I'm new to BeautifulSoup